# Borel sigma-algebra vs Toplogical space on R

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

i got two questions on measure theory:

1. The Borel sigma algebra on R is not containing all the toplogical space on R. At the other hand it is generated by all the open sets of the topological space. If we take all the unions of open sets in the topological space ( uncountable unions are not allowed in the Borel space ) we get an open set which belongs to the topological space but also to the Borel space because it is open and thus participates as generator of B(R).
   Can we identify such open sets as uncountable unions of other open sets clearly ? The fact that they are open, does it not contradict the other fact that they are part of the sets which generate the Borel sigma algebra ? In other words, which sets belong to the topological space but not to B(R) ?
2. Are the Vitali sets open and thus do they belong to the topological space on R ?

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but the Borel sigma algebra contains *all* open sets (by definition) and so it contains the topology. Also, as a result a non-measurable set cannot be open.

Comment: B(R) is itself not a topology. I made a mistake in confusing the two different things: B(R) contains the topology on R and B(R) is a topology. Thanks for the comment.